# Disconnecting lithium battery pack during charging

Tags: arduino, relay, battery-charging

I'm building a smart battery consisting of a 3s6p Li-Ion battery and Arduino. The battery pack I'll be using came with a 12V 5A PSU which overheats when charging the battery from empty. I have a 20V 3.5A power brick to replace this. I want to use a CC/CV buck module in conjunction with the 20v PSU to charge the cells safely.

I also want to be able to have the load (max 3A) connected while charging. From my basic understanding, this would mean I have to disconnect the battery from the rest of the circuit as well as the output as the voltage would fluctuate. Assuming this is correct and or standard practice I've figured a DPDT relay would work to disconnect both the positive and ground. A second buck converter could then power the load and the rest of the circuit.

I've designed a circuit that I think can achieve all of the above. This is by far the most complex project I've tackled and I guess I need some advice as to whether or not my assumptions are correct and if the circuit I've designed will achieve the above criteria without setting my house on fire. Here it is:

[image: Circuit diagram]

Comment: What makes you think that you have to disconnect the load from the battery while charging? (Also, does your battery have an integrated balancer?)

Comment: A CC/CV buck isn't sufficient to safely charge Li-Ion batteries.  It's much safer to use a charger IC meant specifically for charging lithium batteries.  They have safety features such as charge termination, watchdog timers, recovery modes, temperature sensing, etc.

Comment: A CC-CV power supply is not a charger. A real lithium battery charger will also stop charging when the battery is full. A simple CC-CV power supply will never stop charging and overcharges and damages the batteries by floating them at CV.

Comment: The battery has a BMS which also does balancing. If the battery is charging in CC mode won't the voltage drop to maintain the current? I'm also concerned about affecting charging if the load is switched on or off.

Comment: BMS is for safety. Not a reason to omit an actual charger whose sole purpose is to charge the batteries and do it with required precision so batteries can be safely charged without damaging them.

Comment: @VBZA Does the BMS have over-voltage protection, too?

Comment: @JonathanS. yes, it cuts out at 4.2V and re-engages at 4.08V

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Contrary to what's been said in the comments, charging a protected(!) lithium-ion battery pack (that has a balancer) with a CC-CV buck converter is perfectly safe - it is, after all, the manufacturer-recommended way of charging lithium-ion batteries. Whether the charging device is labeled as a "charger" or as a "power supply" is insignificant as long as it follows the proper CC-CV charging curves. A simple constant-voltage buck converter with a current limit *does* follow these proper curves.

The only thing that a buck converter lacks is charge termination; however, [float charging lithium-ion cells is okay](https://www.electronicsweekly.com/market-sectors/power/float-charging-lithium-ion-cells-2006-02/) (but you should back off on the charging voltage a bit; 4V is safe for most lithium-ion cells). Lithium-ion cells will *not* continue to charge forever if 4V is applied constantly to their terminals (after all, 4V is below their open-circuit voltage).

To get back to your actual question: The relay and second 12V buck converter aren't actually needed. You can draw power directly from the batteries while they're charging. This just means that the charging current will be slightly lower (any current drawn by your circuit will come directly from the charger and bypass the batteries).

Before you connect the CC-CV buck converter to your batteries, make sure that it doesn't draw excess current from them when the 20V charging source is disconnected. Also, check that the current limit actually works (measure the output current into a low-value resistor) and ensure that the output voltage is accurate (you should aim for 12V for your 3S battery pack, not the full 12.6V that it's rated for, to extend battery life and allow for float charging). Also make sure that the buck's output voltage tolerance is tight enough so that it never rises above 12.15V (4.05V per cell). If in doubt, set it to a lower voltage like 11.6V (3.9V per cell).

If you ever accidentally over-discharge the pack, be extremely careful with it and try to trickle charge it outside of your circuit before you put it back into service (or just replace it). The cells might get damaged despite the BMS. If your buck converter has an enable pin, you can use that to disable charging in case the battery got over-discharged.

Alternatively, replace the CC-CV buck with an actual lithium-ion charger IC (without balance connections; your BMS already handles those). Using an actual charger IC doesn't change the fact that you can power the circuit with the battery while it's being charged, though.

Comment: If you float charge at around 4V and you have a BMS with safety features built in you might get away with a CC/CV buck.  Hopefully the accuracy and drift of the 4V output is well better than 5%, and the cells aren't charged at extreme temperatures.  Hopefully the BMS will prevent charging if the cells fall below the safe charging level when partial copper decomposition appears on anode-shorted cells due to over-discharge.  At that point they need low current recovery charging in order not to overheat, which a CC/CV buck won't do. Personally, I'd rather use a dedicated charger IC.

Comment: Quite a few protection circuits do not have active cell balancing, although some of them are laid out for the additional MOSFETs and resistors. They may only monitor the cells and control excessive discharge, and perhaps disable charging if any cell exceeds a safe value. You can purchase protection BMS circuits with active balancing, but at a considerably higher cost.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to provide this comprehensive explanation. It's cleared up a lot of things for me. I have started putting this circuit together and as you suspected the cc/cv module draws current from the battery when the 20v supply is disconnected. I've tried to find a solution, had a look here: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/442780/how-to-block-reverse-current-from-battery-to-charger-dc-buck-cc-cv-module. Ordering specialised ICs will take weeks and I can't seem to find a P-mosfet with the right specs. Tried a relay and it just stays latched after 20v removed.

Comment: In that case, your CC/CV module is unfortunately not suitable for the task. There's no way around a specialized charger chip then, which will have the added advantage of supporting trickle charge in case the cells get over-discharged accidentally, as well as proper charge termination.